# How to quit an unsatisfying job?

Tags: resignation, job-change, mental-health

As mentioned in the title, I'm currently in a job that doesn't satisfy my expectations. I'm working as a systems engineer in a renowned private hospital group. I have a lot of experience in web development and was promised that I would be working with the technology I've previously learnt (like ASP.NET Core, Vue.js) and learn new web technologies, such as React.js.

The reality turned out to be quite different. The reason why they hired me, was so that they could have someone who would work on their intranet, which has been implemented in a horrible way. We're a team of five and only me and the intern are working on the intranet. The other three have no experience in web development at all and are concerned with the ITSM system that they're using across the entire company, which is very outdated (They're currently working on a replacement). I'm not allowed to revamp the intranet because of the workload that they have. According to them, they need someone to pass tasks from the load which would mean that I wouldn't have enough time to work on a new solution, even though I never felt this way about the work load. I would always have enough time to work on something like this.

I have been working there for about 6 months now and have voiced my dissatisfaction. They have stated that there is going to be a time where I can work on a new intranet with the technologies I desire, but I believe that this is going to take another 6-8 months until this happens. I also suspect that the way I imagine the revamp to go is not going to be according to my imagination.

I'm not happy there and I sometimes feel like I'm wasting my time. My well-being has also taken a toll through all this because not only have I been dissatisfied but also my relationship with my manager and co-workers has been negative at times because I couldn't integrate myself in the system that they're using since I received no introduction and explaining things was frowned upon. Sometimes it would be ok to ask but sometimes I would receive comments such as "You should know this by now, are you really from the IT?". This resulted in me losing motivation to work and feeling down and out for a long time.

I have voiced this as well and the situation has improved but I still notice the remnants of this negativity. Either way, I'm unsure whether I should quit because sometimes I do actually enjoy the tasks that I get, especially the ones related to implementing new and better things on the Intranet. However, I feel like there are no prospects for me to develop myself in the software development direction I want to go. If there are any prospects, they would be limited and I wouldn't get to all the "cool stuff" I want to learn and do simply because they view additional technologies as unnecessary since they rely so much on the ITSM tool which currently used.

I'm afraid that I might get a bad review from my boss and also that this would be the wrong decision. It's actually pretty clear that I should quit my job, but I struggle with the how. Unfortunately, I don't have a back-up job but I still live with my parents and have considered working at my dad's business. Since he's doing a one-man show over there, he would be very happy for any kind of help I can give him. I get along well with my dad but sometimes I struggle a lot with him because of personal reasons I won't get into. But I believe that this relationship can be improved.

Any advice or help would be appreciated!

Comment: You obviously don't like it there. Do move on

Answer (score 19):

> It's actually pretty clear that I should quit my job, but I struggle
> with the how.

It's a simple, standard process:

- Find a new job: one that meets your personal and professional needs
- Get and accept an offer
- Give your notice
- Work your notice period in a professional manner
- Start your new job and move on with your life

You found this job, but it just isn't working out. You indicate you have a lot of experience. You'll find a better job.

This time around, make sure you ask lots of questions during the interview process to make sure this job is a good fit. You don't want to be looking again in 6 months.

Comment: I would add one thing:  decline an exit interview, or at least the part where you complain about the employer.  No need to waste time.

Comment: Perfect answer :)